# Java Timer does not wait previous TimerTask to be finished before the new one is started

Tags: java, timer, modal-dialog

I am writing an app in Java and I am stuck in the following: After an amount of time, a inputDialog(JOptionPane) is shown. Because the intervals are short, ie 10 secs, if I delay interacting with the first dialog, then the second will appear immediately after I will. Is there any way to avoid this? I thought that program would wait for my input.

Code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            String task = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What are you doing now???", "");
          }
        }, 10*1000, 10*1000);
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using a java.util.Timer if this is a Swing application as it risks calling Swing code off of the Swing event thread. Consider using a Swing Timer instead and testing if the previous dialog has been closed before opening the next.

Comment: The only Swing component is this dialog, I have no other frames. Should I proceed?

Comment: Personally, change the program's design from the start. I'd create a complete swing GUI and not throw dialogs at the user.

Comment: I agree but I dont need some more than an input dialog...it is for personal use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check in your run method if the task is already running, and when it is, return.

Add a variable

```
static boolean isRunning = false;
```

to your TimerTask implementation class. Your run method then looks like this:

```
 public void run() {
     if (isRunning == false) {
         isRunning = true;

         // your code

         isRunning = false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Although I adopted another implementation, I like this one.

Comment: @py_script Please mention which alternative adopted and implemented by you so it would be helpful to others.

Comment: I am seeing a small chance that something slips through the cracks here, as there is no guarantee that `isRunning = true` is executed immediately after the check. We may run into a race-condition where another thread executes faster. The only way to secure this properly is by synchronizing threads IMHO, but then we may see backpressure as timer events build up if they take longer.

Answer (score 2):

Try stopping/starting the `Timer` from inside the `TimerTask`

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        timer.stop();
        String task = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What are you doing now???", "");
        timer.start();
      }
    }, 10*1000, 10*1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: Do I have to do this in a separate block or inside the run method?

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]
The below code does not use "scheduleAtFixedRate" so its conclusion might be wrong...
(Never trust those guys on the internet :)

[Original]
I favor of those who are as lazy as I am:

The timer waits. It will run only one task at a time.

(** tested with java-1.8.0-openjdk)

Code (scala, but yet, it is using Java timer):

```
import java.util.{Timer, TimerTask}

object O {
    val iGen = new AtomicInteger()

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val timer = new Timer()

        val timerTask = new TimerTask {
            override def run(): Unit = {
                val tid = iGen.incrementAndGet()
                println(s"--- task #$tid started")
                Thread sleep(5000)
                println(s"--- task #$tid done")
            }
        }

        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--- task #1 started
--- task #1 done
--- task #2 started
--- task #2 done
--- task #3 started
--- task #3 done
--- task #4 started
--- task #4 done
--- task #5 started
--- task #5 done
--- task #6 started
--- task #6 done
--- task #7 started
--- task #7 done
--- task #8 started
--- task #8 done
--- task #9 started
--- task #9 done
--- task #10 started
--- task #10 done
--- task #11 started
--- task #11 done
--- task #12 started
--- task #12 done
--- task #13 started
--- task #13 done
--- task #14 started
--- task #14 done
--- task #15 started
--- task #15 done
--- task #16 started
--- task #16 done
--- task #17 started
--- task #17 done
--- task #18 started
--- task #18 done
--- task #19 started
--- task #19 done
--- task #20 started
--- task #20 done
--- task #21 started
--- task #21 done
--- task #22 started
--- task #22 done
--- task #23 started
--- task #23 done
--- task #24 started
--- task #24 done
--- task #25 started
--- task #25 done
--- task #26 started
--- task #26 done
--- task #27 started
--- task #27 done
--- task #28 started
--- task #28 done
--- task #29 started
--- task #29 done
--- task #30 started
--- task #30 done
--- task #31 started
--- task #31 done
--- task #32 started
--- task #32 done
--- task #33 started
--- task #33 done
--- task #34 started
--- task #34 done
--- task #35 started
--- task #35 done
--- task #36 started
--- task #36 done
--- task #37 started
--- task #37 done
--- task #38 started
```